I need to restrict only | Pipe special character from input in angular
<dx-text-box (onKeyDown)="Submit($event)"
 (onValueChanged)="somthing()" maxLength="100"[(value)]="Description">
<dx-validator><dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Description is required"></dxi-validation-rule><dxi-validation-rule type="pattern" [pattern]="PipePattern"
message="Special character '|' is not allowed!"></dxi-validation-rule></dx-validator>
</dx-text-box>

this is my html code
ts code:
PipePattern="^[(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#&()\-/$=<>?])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#&()\-/$=<>?]]*$";
I just need to restrict user from entering | (pipe) in description, all other character should be allowed including space. I am using dev express text box here.
Note: I don't know much about regular expression.

Out of interest: why? Aesthetic choice?
